# Defining pieces of data with loops (for and if)

Tags: r

I have a large series of data, but here is just one representative example.

```
data=c(0,0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1,0,0,0.3,0.1,0.1,0,0)
```

I am trying to define separate events that start with first value that differs from zero and ends with last value that is not equal to zero (event must not include zero values). So in this case I would have three events: (0.1,0.1,0.1), (0.2,0.1) and (0.3,0.1,0.1). First I tried to define first number that is not zero:

```
events <- list()
for(i in seq(1,length(data),1)){
if(data[i]==0) next
else start1=i
```

When the loop finds the first value that differs from zero I tried with another for loop (and also repeat) to define the end of event, but non of my solution worked...

Then I tried to define new lists with parts of data:

```
events[[paste('ev', end1-start1)]] = data[start1:end1]
rm(start1); rm(end1)
}
```

I forgot that start and end are functions when i changed names of variables...
Thank you

Comment: Start with `rle(data == 0)` .  `rle` is one of my favorite functions for finding streaks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

Define data

```
data=c(0,0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1,0,0,0.3,0.1,0.1,0,0)
```

Use `rle` (as independently suggested by Carl Witthoft in comments)

```
rr <- rle(data!=0)
cc <- c(0,cumsum(rr$lengths))
v <- rr$values
```

This next bit *could* be done with a loop. `mapply` is a bit more magical.
You might want to add `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to prevent the results from being collapsed
into a matrix if the results happen to all be the same length.

```
mapply(function(start,end) data[start:end],
   cc[v]+1,cc[v]+rr$length[v])

## [[1]]
## [1] 0.1 0.1 0.1

## [[2]]
## [1] 0.2 0.1

## [[3]]
## [1] 0.3 0.1 0.1
```

Note that I haven't tested this very extensively ...

Answer (score 4):

Using `rle` as well, but different way of getting the result:

```
rr  <- rle(data != 0)
idx <- rr$lengths[rr$values]
split(data[data != 0], rep(seq(idx), idx))

# $`1`
# [1] 0.1 0.1 0.1

# $`2`
# [1] 0.2 0.1

# $`3`
# [1] 0.3 0.1 0.1
```

Comment: is `== TRUE` redundant?  Why not define `rr <- rle(data != 0)` first to avoid retyping and recomputing it twice? i.e. `rr <- rle(data != 0); idx <- rr$lengths[rr$values]`

Comment: @BenBolker, no idea why I dint assign it first. Modified now.